# JavaFX - something similar like VBox but what wouldn't autofit

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having a little trouble finding something similar to `VBox` (to set elements on top of each other), but that wouldn't autofit. I'm trying to create Gantti diagram, but if i create rectangles with small width and add text into `VBox` aswell and the number width is larger than my rectangle width it will choose number width. It becomes a problem when i start to put things next to each other with `HBox()`.

I can show you the picture of it:
[image]

As seen from image, there is a whitespace between blue and black rectangles, these are caused by the width of numbers being higher than width of rectangles. I would like to ignore the number width and get rectangles exactly next to each other (Although keep the number in the center of middle rectangle). `HBox` has been created with value of 0 so there's no gap.

My code is written fully in estonian and i will provide an example code which is not from actual program but features the idea that i've done:

```
        HBox hbox1 = new HBox();
        VBox vbox1 = new VBox();
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(0,0,30,30);
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(0,0,5,50);
        r2.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle(0,0,30,30);
        Text t1 = new Text();
        t1.setText(Integer.toString(222));
        vbox1.getChildren().addAll(r2,t1);
        hbox1.getChildren().addAll(r1,vbox1,r3);
        root.setBottom(hbox1);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of ways of doing this can be as follows:

Set the text node as unmanagable for its parent and determine its place manually

```
Text t1 = new Text();
t1.setText(Integer.toString(222));
t1.setManaged(false);
t1.setLayoutX(-t1.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2);
t1.setLayoutY(r2.getHeight() + t1.getLayoutBounds().getHeight());
```